# Required Field Validation only when field is visible in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, datepicker, jquery-validate

I have a checkbox where you can hide/show a datepicker field.

But when the datepicker field is hidden there has to be no validation.

This is the checkbox:

```
  @Html.CheckBox("showEindDatum", (Request.Form["showEindDatum"] ?? string.Empty).Contains("true"))
```

And this is the datepicker:

```
   @FormGroupHelper.CreateFormGroup(Html, m => m.EindDatum, Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m.EindDatum).Min(Model.EindDatum.HasValue ? Model.EindDatum.Value : DateTime.Today).Format("dd-MM-yyyy").ParseFormats(new string[] { "ddMMyyyy" }))
```

The properties of this fields are looking like this:

```
 [Display(Name = "Einddatum wijziging")]
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Messages), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Global_Validatie_VeldVerplicht")]
        public DateTime? EindDatum { get; set; }

 public bool showEindDatum { get; set; }
```

And this is the jquery of it:

```
if ($('#showEindDatum').prop('checked')) {

            $(".EinddatumDatepicker").show();
            $("#meldingEindDatumCheck").show();

        }
        else {
            $(".EinddatumDatepicker").hide();
            $("#meldingEindDatumCheck").hide();
        }

        $("#showEindDatum").on("click", function ()
        {
            $(".EinddatumDatepicker").toggle(this.checked);
            $("#meldingEindDatumCheck").toggle(this.checked);

        });
```

So what I have to change that there is no validation when the datepicker field is hidden?

Thank you

So you mean this:

```
 $.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: null });

        if ($('#showEindDatum').prop('checked')) {

            $(".EinddatumDatepicker").show();
            $("#meldingEindDatumCheck").show();
            $("#geenEinddatumIngevuld").hide();

        }
        else {
            $(".EinddatumDatepicker").hide();
            $("#meldingEindDatumCheck").hide();
            $("#geenEinddatumIngevuld").show();

        }

        $("#showEindDatum").on("click", function () {           
            $(".EinddatumDatepicker").toggle(this.checked);
            $("#meldingEindDatumCheck").toggle(this.checked);
            $("#geenEinddatumIngevuld").toggle(this.checked);

        });
```

this doesn't work.

But the form has also a post method, like this:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Formulier", "PersoneelsDossier", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "PDForm", name = "PDForm" }))
}
```

You mean like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        //$("#PDForm").data("validator").settings.ignore = ".ignore, :hidden";     

        if ($('#showEindDatum').prop('checked')) {

            $(".EinddatumDatepicker").show();
            $("#meldingEindDatumCheck").show();
            $("#geenEinddatumIngevuld").hide();

        }
        else {
            $(".EinddatumDatepicker").hide();
            $("#meldingEindDatumCheck").hide();
            $("#geenEinddatumIngevuld").show();

        }

        $("#showEindDatum").on("click", function () {           
            $(".EinddatumDatepicker").toggle(this.checked);
            $("#meldingEindDatumCheck").toggle(this.checked);
            $("#geenEinddatumIngevuld").toggle(this.checked);

        });

        $.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: null });

 });
```

You mean like this:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: null });

        if ($('#showEindDatum').prop('checked')) {

            $(".EinddatumDatepicker").show();
            $("#meldingEindDatumCheck").show();
            $("#geenEinddatumIngevuld").hide();

        }
        else {
            $(".EinddatumDatepicker").hide();
            $("#meldingEindDatumCheck").hide();
            $("#geenEinddatumIngevuld").show();

        }

        $("#showEindDatum").on("click", function () {           
            $(".EinddatumDatepicker").toggle(this.checked);
            $("#meldingEindDatumCheck").toggle(this.checked);
            $("#geenEinddatumIngevuld").toggle(this.checked);

        });
```

Doesn't work

Comment: You use a conditional validation attribute, for example a [foolproof](https://github.com/leniel/foolproof) `[RequiredIf]` attribute (or to learn how to write your own, refer [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)

Answer (score 2):

By default jQuery validate ignores hidden fields, elements with zero width and height, those with css display:none and any elements with an invisible parent (using same criteria).

The ignore setting can however be overridden by adding the following script

```
// By default validator ignores hidden fields.
// change the setting here to ignore nothing
$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: null });
```

Comment: Thank you. but that doesn't work. I update the post.

Comment: @thecodeEngine have you put before your validation run?

Comment: What do you mean? the Jquery is under the form fields. Yes.

Comment: @thecodeEngine this need to be put immediate under jquery validate load

Comment: @thecodeEngine try by putting the first statement in document ready function

Comment: Not sure what this answer has to do with the question (OP has stated they do not want validation if its hidden)

Comment: But what is now the solution?? Because It stil doesn't work

Comment: you mean: [RequiredIf] but that is not the solution.